# Is it impossible to secure this system

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

I have encountered a seemingly impossible task in a coursework specification which the entire class is struggling with, I will try to summarise as concisely as possible:

1. A file has a "read" and "write" password where the passwords are not the same.
2. A user may write or create a file if they know the "Write" password of the filename.
3. Similarly a user may read the contents of the file if they know the "Read" password.
4. The source code of the entire program is available to any attacker of the system because the program is passed to users via USB.
5. There is no way to create a keystore seemingly as there is no way to enter a master password to store keys per file.
6. No keys/passwords may appear in plaintext.
7. Commands are in the form java -e file pass1 and java -d file pass2 for write and read respectively, there is no way to pass in both passwords.

My musings so far:

1. I store the passwords hashed and salted in the source code, which is quite secure (as far as the spec goes)
2. I cannot use an AES (or any symmetric) key because it would be the same for read and write. So a "read" user can easily get their AES key if just one naive key is used for read/write, thus they could spoof doing write operations.
3. I cannot keep a copy of the file and encrypt using two AES keys because that would make the files go out of sync., so say user 1 writes to file 1, how can the read copy of the file encrypted using just a read key keep track of the changes without being to decrypt the write portion.
4. Generating public/private key pairs leave me nowhere to store them as I'd need to encrypt the keystore with a master password - the spec forbids the use of any commands but the ones they prescribe.

My question is... is this impossible? Or is there a way. I've been stuck for a week, as have the entire class. my professor claims there is a solution.

Comment: What commands are you allowed? Are you explicitly forbidden from using asymmetric ciphers?

Comment: I am only allowed an encrypt (write) and decrypt (read) operation which takes a filename and password as its params. I am not forbidden, however, how would I use them without revealing information? If I try to store keypairs then I need to encrypt the keypairs so that they are not stolen right?

Comment: yes you do. But you could use a different key to encrypt each member of the keypair. That is, you encrypt the 'public key' with AES, using the write password as the key, and you encrypt the 'private key' using the read password as the key.

Comment: Damn, I am kicking myself, I think that'll work without revealing any info or violating accesses! I'll try implement it now

Comment: Sorry, false alarm (per the spec). Your idea is really good but the spec stringently says that say a write user has to type "java -encrypt file password" in which he is doing a WRITE operation, when I generate my keypair for the first time for that file, I don't know the read password, so I can only protect the keypair with the WRITE generated key. But a read user can't decrypt it :(

Comment: In that case, how is the read password set?

Comment: We've been given the passwords per file in a text file (so I've stored hashed + salted versions of them in the source code of the program). They are preset by an administrator I guess in a real world situation

Comment: So wait, you're provided file-writeKey-readKey tupples, but you need to write your system such that the write key is set at file creation, by the user? If the read key is not defined beforehand, there's no way the system could create it and share it with the read user without revealing it to the write user. Its a secret sharing problem; if the system and a user do not share some secret to be used as/to create a key, they cannot communicate securely.

Comment: Seemingly so, as we are only allowed to use those two commands and it says in the spec to follow it stringently and any deviations results in a loss of 5 marks. So as far as I know I can't do a pre-fetch of the passwords and encrypt asymmetric keys safely (deleting the password listing after) because that'd mean I'd have to submit the passwords in plaintext to the submission (which is not allowed). 

I agree completely though, I don't think as the spec is written it's possible. I guess in the following days we will go to the lab, and see if maybe there's a specification error somewhere

Comment: Is [The Nutty Professor](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5523981/the-nutty-professor) a class mate, the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35627186/451475) seems to have a similarity.

Comment: It looks very similar however "This identification is a number and we have no control over its characteristics. " does not match to the information in my spec., unless he changed the details to obscure the nature of the coursework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution as hinted by one of the demonstrators of the module.

We can use the hashed and salted passwords to protect two instances of the AES key which is randomly generated.

... I won't even comment how insecure this is, with the hashes and salts available to any attacker using the system, who can just make their own instance of the program that doesn't check the password hashes, but then again they can always RAM inspect in any case since it's USB based.